# How do I unlock the Mario house?

Tags: nintendogs-and-cats

When does the Mario house and the Mario items unlock in the American version of Nintendogs and Cats for 3DS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the UK version of Nintendogs + Cats and I unlocked the Mario house when I got around 4500 owner points. I'm not sure if it is different in the US version.

Comment: Thanks, I'm assuming its going to be the same, almost to that point in owner points. :]

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Nintendogs Wiki](http://nintendogs.wikia.com/wiki/Mario_Style), the Mario Style house is unlocked by getting 4,200 Owner Points or by playing for 17 days. It costs $4,000 to purchase.

This applies to all versions of *Nintendogs + Cats*, regardless of region.